# How to prove this matrix inequality $\det(A+B)\ge 2^n\sqrt{\det(A)\det(B)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

**Question:**

Let $A_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n}$ be positive Hermitian matrices.

> Show that
>   $$\det(A+B)\ge 2^n\sqrt{\det(A)\det(B)}.$$

I know that
$$\det(A+B)\ge \det(A)+\det(B)$$

But my problem is that I can't,(maybe this is an old reslut,and also I can't find it),

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a corollary of Minkowski's Determinant Theorem: $\det(A+B)^\frac{1}{n}\geq \det(A)^\frac{1}{n}+\det(B)^\frac{1}{n}.$ Apply AM-GM inequality to the right-hand side.

Comment: this can AM-GM inequality? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking?

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a bit late for an answer, but the following theorem is proven in "Linear Algebra" by Lax in chapter 10.

Let $A$ and $B$ be self-adjoint, positive, $n \times n$ matrices.  Then for all $0<t<1,$
\begin{align}
\det(tA + (1-t)B) \geq (\det A)^{t}(\det B)^{1-t}.
\end{align}
Your answer follows with $t = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It's never too late for a good answer!

Comment: Can you send me pdf document or links ? Thanks you very much!